# ffmpeg: trim / concat results in different length videos

Tags: ffmpeg

Im experimenting with the `trim` and `concat` filters.

I wanted to simply split up a video into **X** chunks, and `concat` it again. I expected the result would be a video with same **frames** / **duration**.

So i have a video encoded with **1 fps** and contains **3 frames**, the duration of this video is **3 seconds**.

i run the following script

`ffmpeg -y -i fps.mp4 -an -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:1[v1];[0:v]trim=1:2[v2];[0:v]trim=2:3[v3];[v1][v2][v3]  concat=n=3:v=1 [out]" -map [out] out.mp4`

The result is a video with a duration of **4 seconds** to inspect the problem i called:

`ffprobe -print_format json -show_frames out.mp4`

It shows that there is now **4** frames?? (here is the dump)

```
ffprobe version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
{
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 100x100, 2 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 16384 tbn, 2 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    "frames": [
        {
            "media_type": "video",
            "stream_index": 0,
            "key_frame": 1,
            "pkt_pts": 0,
            "pkt_pts_time": "0.000000",
            "pkt_dts": 0,
            "pkt_dts_time": "0.000000",
            "best_effort_timestamp": 0,
            "best_effort_timestamp_time": "0.000000",
            "pkt_duration": 16384,
            "pkt_duration_time": "1.000000",
            "pkt_pos": "48",
            "pkt_size": "857",
            "width": 100,
            "height": 100,
            "pix_fmt": "yuv444p",
            "pict_type": "I",
            "coded_picture_number": 0,
            "display_picture_number": 0,
            "interlaced_frame": 0,
            "top_field_first": 0,
            "repeat_pict": 0,
            "chroma_location": "left"
        },
        {
            "media_type": "video",
            "stream_index": 0,
            "key_frame": 0,
            "pkt_pts": 16384,
            "pkt_pts_time": "1.000000",
            "pkt_dts": 16384,
            "pkt_dts_time": "1.000000",
            "best_effort_timestamp": 16384,
            "best_effort_timestamp_time": "1.000000",
            "pkt_duration": 16384,
            "pkt_duration_time": "1.000000",
            "pkt_pos": "1053",
            "pkt_size": "146",
            "width": 100,
            "height": 100,
            "pix_fmt": "yuv444p",
            "pict_type": "B",
            "coded_picture_number": 2,
            "display_picture_number": 0,
            "interlaced_frame": 0,
            "top_field_first": 0,
            "repeat_pict": 0,
            "chroma_location": "left"
        },
        {
            "media_type": "video",
            "stream_index": 0,
            "key_frame": 0,
            "pkt_pts": 32768,
            "pkt_pts_time": "2.000000",
            "best_effort_timestamp": 32768,
            "best_effort_timestamp_time": "2.000000",
            "pkt_duration": 16384,
            "pkt_duration_time": "1.000000",
            "pkt_pos": "1199",
            "pkt_size": "19",
            "width": 100,
            "height": 100,
            "pix_fmt": "yuv444p",
            "pict_type": "B",
            "coded_picture_number": 3,
            "display_picture_number": 0,
            "interlaced_frame": 0,
            "top_field_first": 0,
            "repeat_pict": 0,
            "chroma_location": "left"
        },
        {
            "media_type": "video",
            "stream_index": 0,
            "key_frame": 0,
            "pkt_pts": 49152,
            "pkt_pts_time": "3.000000",
            "best_effort_timestamp": 49152,
            "best_effort_timestamp_time": "3.000000",
            "pkt_duration": 16384,
            "pkt_duration_time": "1.000000",
            "pkt_pos": "905",
            "pkt_size": "148",
            "width": 100,
            "height": 100,
            "pix_fmt": "yuv444p",
            "pict_type": "P",
            "coded_picture_number": 1,
            "display_picture_number": 0,
            "interlaced_frame": 0,
            "top_field_first": 0,
            "repeat_pict": 0,
            "chroma_location": "left"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried different things, and everything seems to work fine if i split a 2 second video (still 1 fps) up and concat again. But something goes wrong when going beyond that?

Here is output from `ffmpeg -i fps.mp4`

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'scripts/fps.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), gbrp(tv, gbr/unknown/unknown), 100x100, 4 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 16384 tbn, 2 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Comment: Share the readout from `ffmpeg -i fps.mp4`

Comment: @Gyan i added the readout now :)

Comment: Add `setpts=0` after each trim. The reason for this anomaly involves code in a couple of places but basically a video is a sequence of frames and you are feeding concat multiple segments of single frames. The timestamp generation code uses mean duration of frames in a segment but that requires multiple frames.

Comment: @Gyan very nice, that fixed the problem! really would love to understand whats going on. Just did another test where i created a 2fps / 6 frame video and use the same code above (without setpts=0) same wierd behavior resulting in a merged video of 7 seconds. By given it 2 fps it should be able to calculate a mean duration of frames?